# Multiprecision Python library that plays well with boost::multiprecision or other options?

Tags: c++, python, boost, floating-point-precision, mpfr

I am working on a project that revolves around multiprecision "complex" numbers, specifically it's a Mandelbrot Set-based app, but with a twist that requires decent correspondence between the output of a (fast) C++ py extension module (boost, cython, or other...) and the pure python modules that might want to use it.

Right now, I'm using boost::multiprecision to wrap the MPFR raw type, and yeah if I just wanted to pass an mpfr_t to python that'd be one thing. However, for this app I need to store the C++ module's result as a string which will be *interpreted* later by a Python module, and needs to give the same number.

BigFloat is supposed to be an MPFR python wrapper, but it doesn't interpret a string literal of an X-precision float *exactly* the same way as boost::multiprecision's data() method.

Does anybody know of a combination of libraries plus an approach that *does* result in an exact correspondence between C++ and Python string literals of arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers?

I can provide code excerpts if needed to illustrate the problem, but figured it was arcane enough that if anybody had the answer, they'd know exactly what I mean and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) which is a Python wrapper for both MPFR and MPC (and GMP). If you can provide an example, I may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I ended up doing! Sorry it took so long to get back here, but yes, `gmpy2` did the trick. My C solution is still slightly faster, so I ended up offering the user the option to choose which MP solution they wanted to use.